# React "Module Not Found" when loading a local image

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am trying to load an image using React using the following code:

```
const DogImage = require("../../public/dog.jpg");
console.log(DogImage);
...

<img src={DogImage} width="100px"/>
```

but I am getting the error:

[image]

the console log statement gives:

[image: t]

Please let me know if you have any suggestions or if I can provide more info!

EDIT: The file listed in the console.log (dist/8ce0...) exists when built

Answer (score 1):

The path is going into the `default` property, which is a special property used by the `import` syntax. Try:

```js
import DogImage from '../../public/dog.jpg';
```

OR

```js
const DogImage = require('../../public/dog.jpg').default;
```

Anything else would require digging into the webpack config.

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't seem to work. The console log gives the correct path and the image exists but it still doesn't appear on the screen (the HTML file icon is gone as well)

Comment: Post the resulting HTML